# How to find when method finished in android for loop

Tags: java

i want to find to know when method finished in for loop in Java

example :

```
for(int i = 0; i< list.size();i++){
Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);
}
```

i want to detect and find Client.check last run and loop finish :)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just have some code outside the loop that will be hit when the loop is finished?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android.  Please tag your questions correctly.

Comment: Is `Client.check` a blocking call?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, inside and outside of for loop.

Inside for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);

    if(i == (list.size()-1)){
        //this is the last iteration of for loop
    }
}
```

Outside for loop.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);
 }
 Log.d(TAG, "For loop finished);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly but I think you made a mistake with the condition. Here is the correction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);
}
```

I changed `list.size` to `i<list.size` so that now the loop will only run while `i` is less than `list.size`.

EDIT: You've fixed the syntax error so if you want to do something once the loop is done, simply add more code below it. Alternatively if you want to do something within the for loop as it loops for the last time maybe you can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);
    if (i == list.size()-1) {
        // do something for the last loop
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to know how detect method finished inside for loop

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what exactly you want to detect then since when the loop is done it goes to the next line. Just add more code below. Or do you want to do something at the same time as the last loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just add some code in the for loop. Like this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Client.check(list.get(i).getUsername);
    System.out.println("Method finished !");
}
```

Comment: thanks bro but Client.Check method spends some time and  i want to run code after finish of this method

Comment: This prints `list.size()` times